# Log in to Hotmail automatically with KeePass?

Tags: gmail, hotmail, keepass

Is it possible to log into Hotmail or Google Mail automatically using a password manager like KeePass? I am trying to use the auto-type feature of this program by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> key combination. For some reason it doesn't work on these two web services, although it does work on other websites.

Comment: After researching a little bit into this problem it is clear to me that these services somehow prevent simulated keystrokes which KeePass uses to auto-type. For this to work I will need a plug-in for my browser that works with KeePass, such as KeeForm mentioned below and KeeFox. Another common problem even when you have these plug-ins installed is that the maximum password length for Hotmail is set to 16 characters. Anything longer than that will result in failed log in, although you can type in more than 16 if you do it manually on the log in page.

Comment: I also noticed that auto-type in KeePass seem to have problems if you visit a website in a different language where it does not say "user name" or "password". For this reason, I think a plug-in of some sort may be a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be there is a problem with your entry which you have made recently. So I'm going to answer you from start. Create a new entry and make sure that you have give the right title name **Gmail**. After this enter your username and password for you `Gmail` account.

[image]

Also you should have to enter the right `URL` of the login page but you can keep it blank also.

Now your entry looks like this

[image]

Now there could be a problem with the Global Key as <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+A</kbd> you can change it through the **Tools>Option** and then click on `Integration` tab and change the `Global auto type` to some other key combination. As when I pressed those combination it launched the other program associated with it.

[image]

But you already tell that its worked on other sites not only these two. Above method is working on my PC without any problem so may be it was your problem. Give it a try. Good luck!

Comment: It worked! Thanks! "Wrong" title! But does it really depend on the title of the website (window name list)? I have made it work with both Google Mail and Hotmail. But for example on the log in page for Hotmail it sometimes says "Welcome to Windows Live" and sometimes "Välkommen till Windows Live" (Swedish), and if you log out of Hotmail and want to log back in the title changes to "Sign In". This makes it almost impossible to use KeePass and auto-type unless you edit the entry in KeePass for every time it does that.

Comment: AFAI think the title is not on the page its shows on the tab when you load any page. For solve to this puzzle you can set any name of **title** but then you have to make notes. See this [article](http://www.howtos.ca/2010/01/advance-usage-of-keepass.html).

Comment: Thanks! That article was actually very helpful. The title of a given web-page or a web-site is shown both in the title bar of the program window and in the tab button (assuming it is a tabbed web browser). This is true for Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: FF, chrome, opera, IE and safari all are tab browsers. Because this is not the matters that the title s showing in tab **Keepass** check it form the page where they coded the page and set the title whatever of the page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Are you saying that KeePass checks the title of the HTML, like so: `<html><head><title>HTML 4 page title like "Email from Google"</title></head><body>document content</body></html>` Is it the `<title>` tag it checks for? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes I mean that, but I'm not much sure its my guess.

Answer (score 1):

**KeeForm** is a popular extension for Keepass that can launch web sites, scan for user name and password fields, and fill in that information for you automatically. It automates the login process for you and is highly configurable.

When you double-click the URL field in KeePass, typically the following steps are carried out automatically for you:

- Start browser
- Open the login web page
- Fill in the Username and Password field
- Click the submit button and login to the site

KeeForm is a Windows application distributed under the GPL license. It has been developed using AutoIt and should run on all (and only) Windows operating systems.

Download KeeForm from [here](http://www.keeform.org/downloads/keeform) and follow this [How to install and use KeeForm](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/keepass-4.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed the installation instructions here: http://www.keeform.org/content/keepass/installation And I have installed the MozRepl from here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/ But I am getting an error message. File/URL: C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KeeForm.exe

Arguments: "https://login.live.com/" "myemail" "mypass" "{ENTERFORM}"

Could not find file

Comment: It was my mistake! I changed KeeFormFF.exe to KeeForm.exe so that I get `C:\Program Files (x86)\KeePass Password Safe 2\KeeForm.exe` and then it worked. But what I really should have done is to change to KeeFormFF.exe in the KeePass integration line: `cmd://"{APPDIR}\KeeForm.exe" "{URL}" "{USERNAME}" "{PASSWORD}" "{ENTERFORM}"` as described in the installation instructions above. But it works now. Although it opens a new Firefox window every time I double click on the URL in KeePass. That's a bit annoying. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You are right, it can't be changed. On the FAQ page of KeeForm this is what it says about opening windows, I quote. "KeeForm does not open new pages in a new TAB. KeeForm always opens a new window."